# Which of the AES classes in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace should I use?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, aes

[The System.Security.Cryptography namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx) has at least 3 different seemingly interchangeable ways to get an object that will perform AES encryption/decryption:

```
using (var aes = Aes.Create())
```

or

```
using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
```

or

```
using (var aes = new AesCng())
```

The first two were introduced in .NET framework version 3.5. The third is much newer; it was introduced in version 4.6.2. One might suspect therefore that it is better than the other 2, but [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescng(v=vs.110).aspx) does not say anywhere that it is recommended to use it in place of the other ones.

The first two each have a code sample. The two samples appear essentially identical.

Which one should I use, and why?

Comment: You want `Aes.Create()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Aes` is an abstract class. I assume that `Aes.Create` returns a system default. This is probably what you want to use. Let the system decide which ones are available and which ones is best to use.

The others are implementation classes.

- `AesCryptoServiceProvider` uses MS CAPI, the older crypto API;
- `AesCng` uses the crypto new generation API introduced in Windows Vista;
- `AesManaged` implements AES in .NET (not mentioned in your post).

You can also use [`Aes.Create(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes.create?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Security_Cryptography_Aes_Create_System_String_) to choose one of the implementations. If possible I would try and avoid using the implementation classes directly.

Only use the implementation classes if you know that using a specific class is explicitly required or, indeed, if the abstract `Aes` class is not available.

---

Note that exposing the crypto implementations in the type system by Microsoft has significant drawbacks; choosing a specific provider may be harder, key based implementation selection may be harder (encryption in hardware) and finally users may be tricked into writing incompatible or inefficient code.

The `CipherSpi` implementation classes in Java e.g. are hidden from view; these are called from the generic `Cipher` class.

Comment: `AesCng` should be used if, and only if, opening a CNG persisted AES key.  Otherwise `Aes.Create()` should be used.  .NET Core 1.0 removed the ability to use AES via any other means, but then brought the public types back for 2.0 (just for API surface compatibility with .NET Framework)

Comment: Maarten - Aes.Create() returns an AesCryptoServiceProvider when used in the experimental code running on my development machine.

Comment: @bartonjs I suppose you could use the `Create("AesCng")` constructor for a CNG persisted AES key as well?

Comment: @Hammerite That makes sense, using fast native code for the actual execution of AES.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Nah, the identifier's way longer than that.  (`Aes.Create(typeof(AesCng).GetName())` => `Aes.Create("System.Security.Cryptography.AesCng, System.Core, PublicKeyToken=31bf[etc], [etc]")`).  Pretty much anyone using \[Algorithm\].Create(string) has an easier way of doing what they want.